# how can i continue a while loop after the condition is False?

Tags: r, dataframe, while-loop, conditional-statements, apply

[image: image of a single column of a dataframe (a = dfmean[,4] )]

I' m trying to calculate The maximum number of days with a continuous decrease  in daily mean temperature.
So, first of all, i' m trying to calculate the number of days with a continuous decrease in daily temperature. After that i will find the maximum number of these values. The problem is that while loop calculates only the first five days with a continuous decrease and stops, as the condition is false. How can i continue with the rest values? OR there is an easier way to do that with apply family?

`a=` dfmean[,4]`i=1 x=0`while`(a[i+1,]<a[i,]) {`  x=x+1
print(x)
i=i+1`

}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your data

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2022-02-01"), as.Date("2022-02-10"), 1), 
                 temp_mean = runif(10) * 10)

df
         Date temp_mean
1  2022-02-01  9.148060
2  2022-02-02  9.370754
3  2022-02-03  2.861395
4  2022-02-04  8.304476
5  2022-02-05  6.417455
6  2022-02-06  5.190959
7  2022-02-07  7.365883
8  2022-02-08  1.346666
9  2022-02-09  6.569923
10 2022-02-10  7.050648
```

Get the maximum number of consecutive decreasing values with `diff` and `rle`

```
df_rle <- rle(diff(df$temp_mean) < 0)

max(df_rle$lengths[df_rle$values], na.rm = T)
[1] 2
```